# What to do to rescue a software project when the only ex‑remote community manager goes rogue?

Tags: software-industry, management, human-resources, termination, social-media

We trusted someone working under a pseudonym to manage our social medias. After 8 months he asked for a rise of over $30,000 in order to continue : for this reason and other minor ones, we let him go 1 week later.

The problem is he was the only person in charge of the Twitter and the public GitHub accounts as well as the only mod of the official Discord and Telegram accounts (he created most of them). **And he reacted initially by insulting and refusing to hand over the control** (just preventing us to publish updates to the code from the private repositories).

But 3 weeks after that, **he went from inactive to mostly rogue** after learning a replacement was hired : **he wiped the official GitHub of all the repositories** and started to ban from the official Telegram/Discord anyone who dare to post a proof of his termination and he even used his usurped ability to make official announcements to **fill an emergency abuse complaint in order to claim the official website, which he then wiped and put for auction $6500 on GoDaddy**. We can’t go to the Police since we only know him as a pseudonym and don’t know in which country he does live.
Of course we set up a mirror and alternative accounts, but while he doesn’t try to scam the old userbase himself, we’re now just 1 mirror among many other ones from scammers who claim to be the official team *(the only thing we have is our code is free from blatant scam commits that attempt to search and upload credentials from users when the software is installed but the average end‑user doesn’t understand computer code)*.

## Question :

Trusting an annon so much power just because he initially performed well, is of course a big reputational failure, and they are other things that could have been done differently before his termination (I personally advised finding a replacement should be done first but couldn’t convince the others), but **what to do now to rescue the project** ?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere finding a replacement is done task. The problem is what to do with the rogue community manager who keep the control of the official medias channels.

Comment: @user2284570 what about "find a replacement for whoever decided to hire him"?

Comment: @PhilipKendall he was elected directly by shareholders after being appointed. It really makes a lot of people.

Comment: Why is this your problem? You didn't make the hiring decision, and cautioned against the termination process. Let the people who created the mess deal with it.

Comment: I'm going to guess this is a [Web3 is Going Just Great](https://web3isgoinggreat.com/) problem. If so, I have no sympathy.

Comment: @Hilmar keeping the software project alive/no forgotten for eating ? Though the only way to keep him was to accept the pay rise.

Comment: @user2284570: Sorry for your situation. But at this point you may have to look elsewhere. If the decision makers are are really that incompetent (which is the most polite word I can come up with) they will self-destruct anyway.

Comment: @user2284570 **DO NOT** post people's names/contact details/telegram handles.

Comment: @PhilipKendall correct, we’re an Ethereum ᴅᴀᴏ than a regular company. We had to only trust him because the project itself is under sanctions so it’s difficult to find someone.

Comment: I feel like this is a very borderline workplace problem. At a workplace, you would *never* have an anonymous whatever. The tax authorities would come knocking if they ever found out you hired someone anonymously and paid them... under the table I guess?

Comment: @nvoigt **I simplified things in my question** but the ᴅᴀᴏ is a decentralized computer program on Ethereum. He requested funding for his role last year, and set up a vote : shareholders did agree on the program and it was the ᴅᴀᴏ program that paid him each quarter (payments managed by computer code). When he requested a rise, a majority of shareholders asked the program to terminate his remuneration.

Comment: Does the DAO program pay or even file taxes?

Comment: And how did he get the acounts and passwords, did the program hand it to him?

Comment: I'm not a blockchain expert of any kind, but isn't the decentralised nature of this stuff supposed to help here?  According to the DAO page I found on ethereum.org they are a "safe way to collaborate with internet strangers."

Comment: @nvoigt he created most the accounts himself. Founders left the project leaving only him on the channel he didn’t create. They are many legit organizations using such programs (Sushiswap is the most well‑known one). **The fact it doesn’t pay taxes isn’t a problem as you can’t put Bitcoin or an Ethereum program code in prison.**

Comment: @mattfreake yes it protects, but not for off‑chain assets (what is outside Ethereum). And by turning against the community, he can turn the project into abandonware and thus destroy the market value of it’s Token and thus attack the money of it’s holders who used it against him (`if I can’t have her nobody will` mode).

Comment: "The fact it doesn’t pay taxes isn’t a problem as you can’t put Bitcoin or an Ethereum program code in prison."  - but the French (or other) authorities certainly can put _you_ in prison.

Comment: Based on updates from the OP it's fairly clear which "project" this is referring to, given that a) classing it as a workplace is a massive stretch and b) the project itself is the subject of strong legal sanctions in the US I'm going to go ahead and close this one.

Comment: @PhilipKendall the program doesn’t pay taxes as a company, but their recipient does.

Comment: why did you let him sit on all access accounts to everything for 3 weeks after he was fired? What you're trying to do now should have been done straightaway

Comment: @motosubatsu - Fairly into cryptocurrency and I have absolutely no idea what the project might be. It doesn’t matter I realize that, but it’s not at all obvious, what the project might be

Comment: @Donald [There's really only one project under sanctions](https://home.treasury.gov/news/press-releases/jy0916).

Comment: @AnnaAG he immediately refused to transfer the accounts. He turned rogue 3 weeks after that.

Comment: @user2284570 so he refused to hand over the accounts after he was fired and you all were just “yeah, sure, that’s cool” with it? You should have started doing something immediately

Comment: @AnnaAG : like with the situation now, we don’t see what we could do.

Answer (score 4):

> Trusting an annon so much power just because he initially performed well, is of course a big reputational failure

It's not just a *reputational* failure - it's a giant, sweeping, nigh-on **catastrophic** failure on multiple fronts. Giving this much control with no failsafes (i.e. ways to maintain control) to a single person who is an ordinary employee is plain vanilla stupidity. Giving it to a pseudonymous person who you have essentially no recourse over is extra special stupidity.

I really hope you know this already, but it bears repeating because if for some reason you don't you need to know it pronto.

> they are other things that could have been done differently before his termination (I personally advised finding a replacement should be done first but couldn’t convince the others),

Getting some form of access to the accounts that they couldn't remove you from would have been the bare minimum, finding a replacement would have been a nice to have.

> what to do now ?

Not going to lie - you're pretty screwed right now. If you haven't already contacted the providers for he accounts the ex-employee controlled to attempt to recover the accounts this has to be step one. I wouldn't hold my breath that you'll succeed unless you've got some decent documentation to wave the providers proving you're the legitimate owners of the accounts but it's got to be worth a go.

Parallel to this you need to be getting the word out to your users any way you can that the previously official channels are compromised at this time and not to be trusted. This is going to be an uphill, possibly futile battle, but it's your only real course.

Alongside the above steps the organisation needs new leadership in this area, because the people who decided this was a good idea in the first place have officially crossed into [too dumb to manage](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TooDumbToLive) territory and the chances are high that this won't be their only catastrophic mistake.

This covers what the organisation should do - but how about you personally? This is much simpler: **Run**, this organisation/project is toast, if this doesn't take it down the next big screwup will. So run away now and take heed that any organisation that is this incompetent is not worth your time in future and add this sort of thing to your deal breaker list.

Comment: I contacted providers and Twiter, but they ask for an official announcement from the other social media (despited being controlled by the rogue person). Though I’m one of the persons who welcomed him. The way he managed to take the main site is a glimpse of who is officialy in control (at least the team’s funds remain safe).

Comment: @user2284570 not a big surprise there really.

Comment: Googling `How to rescue a Telegram Channel from a rogue admin` doesn’t give meanfull results too.

Comment: Probably because to all intents and purposes said admin *is* the legitimate controller of the account from telegram's POV, it's highly likely the existing accounts are *gone and not coming back*

Comment: Though 1 of the admins is a bot managed by 1inchs https://github.com/1inch/shieldy. But I don’t how to reach them.

Comment: @user2284570 at this point you're rearranging deck chairs on the *Titanic*

Comment: `Parallel to this you need to be getting the word out to your users any way you can that the previously official channels are compromised at this time and not to be trusted. This is going to be an uphill, possibly futile battle, but it's your only real course.` The problems is scammers says things like `myChannelName is the only official channel. Do not trust scammers`.

Comment: @user2284570 yep, precisely why I labelled it and uphill/futile battle. "Don't trust scammers" is ironic since that's precisely what the org did in the first place - and is now reaping the benefits

Comment: @user2284570 This question looks similar to a previous question. The only valid response is what is said here - RUN. I would add: Get everything in writing so that you have a defense when authorities knock on your door. Have proof that you have left this project and are now working on projects that are not under legal sanctions. Be a witness for the prosecution. Yes, it is hard to walk away from large amounts of money, but doing so builds character especially when done for the right reasons. Character pays off in the long run far more than these projects do.

Answer (score -1):

- Contact Dischord/Gitlab/etc to find out what, if any, procedures they have for this kind of problem.
- Start building up replacement channels as quickly as possible. Use any channels you do have control of to promote these over the compromised one
- Start polishing your CV to find a job somewhere with better decision makers.

Comment: `Dischord/Gitlab/etc` asks for a post on an other social media (controlled by the rogue person) and ignores the proving documents.

Comment: As I said in the questions there is many many replacement channels. But only 1 of them is not from scammers.